# Broadcom BCM4321 cannot find networks

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I've spend a couple of hours now trying to get my wifi card working. I moved the PCI-card from a working machine to a new one. Both running Ubuntu 12.04. The card worked fine in the first machine but now it cannot find any wireless networks. I'm using **wl** driver as it was told to be working with **BCM4321** chipset. And I used this page as a guide for installing: [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#A12.04_.28Precise_Pangolin.29_-*12.10*.28Quantal_Quetzal.29](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#A12.04_.28Precise_Pangolin.29_-_12.10_.28Quantal_Quetzal.29)

I hope somebody can give an advice to help my misery :) Details below.

dmesg (**BCM4329** looks suspicious as the chipset should be **BCM4321**):

```
root@mymachine:/# dmesg | grep -e wl -e eth1
[    1.425064] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[    1.429110] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    1.479959] INFO @wl_cfg80211_attach : Registered CFG80211 phy
[    1.526081] eth1: Broadcom BCM4329 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.20.155.1 (r326264)
[  988.710494] INFO @wl_cfg80211_attach : Registered CFG80211 phy
[  988.737879] eth1: Broadcom BCM4329 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.20.155.1 (r326264)
[ 2083.164833] ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get : error (-1)
[ 2083.164840] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_tx_power : error (-1)
```

lspci:

```
root@mymachine:/# lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4 04:05.0 Network controller
[0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4321 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4329] (rev 01)
```

iwconfig:

```
root@mymachine:/# iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth1      IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=200 dBm
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

virbr0    no wireless extensions.
```

lshw (Is **driver=wl0** OK?):

```
root@mymachine:/# lshw -C network
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4321 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 5
       bus info: pci@0000:04:05.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 01
       serial: 00:21:29:6d:7b:98
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.20.155.1 (r326264) latency=32 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:21 memory:fdafc000-fdafffff
```

lsmod (The driver doesn't really communicate with the kernel right?):

```
root@mymachine:/# lsmod | grep wl
wl                   3074978  0
cfg80211              499466  1 wl
lib80211               14381  2 wl,lib80211_crypt_tkip
```

The changes I made to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf (added the 3 last ones):

```
# replaced by b43 and ssb.
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma
blacklist b43
```

iwlist scanning:

```
root@mymachine:/# iwlist eth1 scanning
eth1      No scan results
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 possible solutions

- Use Ethernet (connect a cable to the router and to your PC) then go to settings manager -> additional drivers and look for where it says use Broacom driver (something like that)
- If you didn't find that driver. Then do this solution `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and then add `blacklist b43` and remove brcmsmac from being blacklisted. then go to `sudo nano /etc/modules` and add `wl` or `brcmsmac`. The latter works on my PC. I have broadcom too but not the same one.
- If none of these solutions work, then upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10, connect to Internet using Ethernet and then go to additional drivers and you will find a Broadcom driver for sure.

`

Comment: Thanks fo an answer. I actually forgot to mention that I have the Broadcom STA wireless driver activated and in use (shows up in the Additional drivers list as well.) I also have an ethernet cable plugged and I'm using the computer over SSH.

Comment: @quinz did you restart the computer after that you activated the driver?

Comment: yes, I've booted it several times since I've tried different things (mostly enabling and disabling different drivers).

Comment: after activating the driver, did you do `sudo apt-get upgrade`? that happened to me, the driver wasn't working well before i did that

Comment: Now that's weird. I did as you said and nothing was upgraded. Yet right after "iwlist eth1 scanning" gave several hits :) Let me check if this will work after the reboot as well.

Comment: Well.. it's broken again. Though before the reboot I got networks listed and I was also able to connect to my home wifi. Now after the reboot it doesn't get any scan results anymore.

Comment: weird, `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did. It doesn't help anymore and since nothing was upgraded anyway I believe something else happened. I guess I'll take another moment to check again that the antenna is properly attached.

Comment: Thanks very much for help though :)

Comment: try the second solution